# How to redirect any input to both https and www?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, webserver

I need `example.com` be redirected to `https://www.example.com`.

My .htaccess file is in the root directory and configured like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex html/home5.html
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

With this configuration, `www.example.com`, `https://example.com` and `http://example.com` are all redirected to `https://www.example.com` (`www.example.com/other.html` and so on work respectively) correctly.

But `example.com` gets redirected to `https://www.example.com/http://www.example.com/` and obviously produces "The requested URL was not found on this server".
Why does this happen? What do I need to change to make it work?

I also don´t understand why with my current configuration `https://example.com` the `www` is added correctly.

Comment: "With this configuration, `www.example.com`, `https://example.com` and `http://example.com` are all redirected to `https://www.example.com`" - Except that the rule you posted does not do that! That rule _only_ redirects HTTP to HTTPS on the same host. If you are seeing a redirect from non-www to www then "something else" is doing that. "But `example.com` gets redirected to `https://www.example.com/http://www.example.com/`" - But in the preceding paragraph you stated the contrary?! `example.com` must either be `http://example.com` or `https://example.com`. Anyway "something else" is doing that.

Comment: "I also don´t understand why with my current configuration https://example.com the www is added correctly." - Again, "something else" must be doing that - either in the server config or your application. The directive you posted does not do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a well working .htacces i'm using for the same problem, with 2 steps :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

First, if the requested url got HTTPS "off", redirect to HTTPS and add the url request query after (saved in $1).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%1/$1 [L]
```

Then, special case for www. subdomain and https on, if matching "www" in the request, redirect to  the same page with https on !

**EDIT : you don't even need the second condition in fact**

Comment: I get the first part, but if I understand you correctly, the second part does the opposite of what I want to achieve. I want to be redirected to both https and www and not https without www. So that a request to `example.com` gets redirected to `https://www.example.com`

Comment: No problem just add www. in the second redirect and remove the 301 flag, updated my post !

Answer (score 0):

**Redirect to https and non-www**

To instead redirect all requests to https and non-www, use the following code instead of the previous:

## Canonical HTTPS/non-WWW

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

As before, place this code in the root .htaccess of your site. Here is what it's doing:

```
Checks if mod_rewrite is available
Checks if HTTPS is off, or if the request includes www
If either condition matches, the request qualifies and is redirected to the https/non-www address
```

When placed in the root .htaccess, this technique covers all requests, providing complete https/non-www canonicalization for your site. Remember to replace the two instances of example.com with your own domain name.

Note: if your site is suffering from duplicate pages because of index.php appended to requested URLs, check out this post at WP-Mix.com that explains how to remove www and index.php from the URL.
Redirect to https and www

The following .htaccess technique redirects qualified requests to the https and www versions of your web pages. Add to your site's root .htaccess file:

## Canonical https/www

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

This code does the following:

```
The first two lines conditionally redirect to https. If the HTTPS variable is set to off, then the request is redirected to https (see notes below if using a proxy).
The second two lines redirect to www. If the request/host does not begin with www., the request is redirected to www.
```

When placed in the root .htaccess, this technique covers all requests, providing complete https/www canonicalization for your site. No editing is required with this code; it's entirely plug-n-play.
Notes if using a proxy

As explained here:

"When behind some forms of proxying, whereby the client is connecting via HTTPS to a proxy, load balancer, Passenger application, etc., the %{HTTPS} variable may never be on and cause a rewrite loop. This is because your application is actually receiving plain HTTP traffic even though the client and the proxy/load balancer are using HTTPS. In these cases, check the X-Forwarded-Proto header instead of the %{HTTPS} variable."

So if you are using some sort of proxy service or similar, add the following line to the above code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
```

So the final result looks like this if using a proxy server:

## Canonical https/www (when using proxy)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

[reference](https://htaccessbook.com/htaccess-redirect-https-www/)